# How can I make a link color not override an animation text color

Tags: html, css, animation, text, colors

I'm building a simple text animation. The animation is supposedly a clickable piece of text that changes color. However, on Microsoft Edge when the link is already visited then the animation will stay purple / blue without any styling.

What should I implement in my code to have the animation clickable on Edge? 
It works on Google Chrome and Firefox, though.

PLEASE NOTE THAT THE LINK IS VISITED WHEN THIS OCCURS

```css
div.coupon {
  height: 30%;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: teal;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-left: 3%;
  padding: 0% 2%;
}
.animation { 
  -webkit-animation-name: animation;   
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s; 
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: animation;
  animation-duration: 3s; 
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animation {
  0%   {color: blue;}
  33%  {color: green;}
  67%  {color: red;}
  100% {color: blue;}
}
@keyframes animation { 
  0%   {color: blue;}
  33%  {color: green;}
  67%  {color: red;}
  100% {color: blue;}
}
a.signup {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="coupon">
  <a href="signup.html" class="signup"><p class="animation">Click on this link to get yourself a free drink on us!</p></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to override the CSS.
For the animation you should use a specific CSS selector.

```
.signup:visited .animation {
    -webkit-animation-name: animation;      
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s; 
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: animation;
  animation-duration: 3s; 
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```